# Duplicate column name... but only if database is case insensitive

Tags: sql, collation, linked-server

I'm trying to query a view on a database that has case sensitive collation from a linked server connection. Something else to note is the view I'm trying to query is basically a wrapper to three indexed views.

The error i'm getting is:

> Duplicate column names are not allowed in result sets obtained through OPENQUERY and OPENROWSET. The column name "ExtPrice" is a duplicate.

In the view I have `EXTPRICE` as well as `ExtPrice`. When I query this view from the server directly, I don't have any issues... but when I try to use the query via a linked server, I get the above error.

- Is this a collation issue?
- How do I use this view via a linked server and still have the query understand that the view is case sensitive?

I apologize in advance if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Why on earth would you have both `EXTPRICE` and `ExtPrice`?

Comment: It's data abstraction from a vendor database.  The idea was to add better data types but still express that the content of the field was the same.  So a date in the vendor database would be called ENTRYDATE and it's stored as a varchar(8)... in the view that references that table, the field would be called EntryDate (in pascal case) and it would actually be a date.  I tried to have the view model the table and just add better data because i'm still pretty new to this vendor database and don't fully understand why they did all the things they did.

Comment: Is it too late to change your abstracted view name to say `v_ExtPrice`?

Comment: well... i think it will be painful because a lot of things touch this view.  but it can be done... just not looking forward to it.

Comment: it will be less painful than continuing to maintain the current design, trust me :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is the result of a case-sensitive collation on the server where your views are located.

And it's why I always grouse about having case-sensitive collations at the server level directly (instead of just using collations at the column-level) as I pointed out here:
http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/practical-sql-server-45/tsql/Collation-SQL-Server-139576

Only, in trying to wrap my brain around how you'd cram a COLLATE clause into a distributed query, I figured there had to be a better way.

And, it looks like you can set some specific options as part of your linked server's definition:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191145.aspx
As that defines how to specify collation options when working with Collations in Distributed Queries.

The issue, however, is that you'll need to use a linked server instead of allowing ad-hoc distributed queries (but they're a security risk/concern anyhow). So I'd recommend using a Linked Server as a better approach anyhow.

Try this link as well - as it provides details on how to control collation settings on the linked server:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839.aspx

And, of course, I'd recommend changing the column name if at all possible.

--Mike

Answer (score 1):

Your column names need to be changed.   If the ENTRYDATE column is text and EntryDate is a Date data type then change ENTRYDATE to ENTRYDATE_TEXT.  Or change EntryDate to EntryDate_Improved.   Even if you could get the linked server view to be happy, future developers working with this are going waste time and possibly introduce bugs because it is very unclear.